# Generalised Hypergeometric Function and Integral: Elementary Question

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I was trying to solve this: $\int_\;\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{3/4}}\;dx$

but I couldn't come up with any good idea so I used *"Wolfram Alpha"*. After then, the trouble began...

The following is the solution according to *"Wolfram"*: 
[image]

I haven't seen ***'Hypergeometric Function'*** in my life never again.So my questions are:

1. How is the above integral equal to this?
2. What exactly is a Hypergeometric Function and how can someone use it?
3. Are there any books that somebody would suggest in order to learn more about this function?

I'm pretty sure this is quite elementary but I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why do not we put $x=\sin y$

Comment: The [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) is simply one of those special functions that appear rather often.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee What do you mean?  It's still not solvable like that.

Comment: Also, if you don't know what something is from WolframAlpha, you can click the thing on the right under "Open code".

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I don't want to know the code, but how did this happen to be the solution..

Comment: Try this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW6sR.png

Comment: Do you *really* need the primitive, or just the integral over $(0,1)$? The latter is simply related with the lemniscate constant (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I was trying to solve this ode: $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=\sqrt {2(1-f(x)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\;$ where $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\;$ and so I concluded to the above integral...

Answer (score 2):

We can use [https://web.archive.org/web/20120127210623/http://www.dsi.unifi.it/~resp/GouldBK.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20120127210623/http://www.dsi.unifi.it/%7Eresp/GouldBK.pdf) : BC1,BS
i.e. and apply combinatorial and Pochhammer identities
To get
$\frac{1}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)\\
k
\end{array}\right)\left(-x^{2}\right)^{k}={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\left(k+\frac{3}{4}-1\right)\\
k
\end{array}\right)\left(-x^{2}\right)^{k}$
$={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\left(k-\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
k
\end{array}\right)\left(x^{2}\right)^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(\left(k-\frac{1}{4}\right)+1\right)}{\left(\Gamma\left(k-\left(k-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\right)k!}x^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)k!}x^{2k}
 $
Integrating
$x\cdot{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)}\frac{\left(x^{2}\right)^{k}}{k!}=x\cdot{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}\frac{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)_{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{k}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_{k}}\frac{\left(x^{2}\right)^{k}}{k!}
 $
$=x\cdot_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{2};x^{2}\right)
 $

The secret to Hypergeometric functions (Generalized or not) is that successive coefficients of the Taylor type expansion ( $ x^{n} /n! $ ) are rational polynomials in n and the coefficients.  These might be considered as things like combinatorial's $\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
k
\end{array}\right)
 $ on steroids. There are various introductions; of greater and lesser prices.  A short one is the reduce-algebra Zeilberger module or you might try Wikipedia.  There is real substance in these functions; and mysteries still remain (at least to me).